# Screen brightness of Dell desktop monitor

Tags: brightness, intel

I am a new user of Ubuntu. It was pre-installed in my new Dell desk top. I am very happy with Ubuntu. But I am having a problem with the brightness of the screen. I am not able to reduce the brightness using the slider in System settings > Brightness and Lock

My system specifications are as follows:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Processor: Intel pentium (R) CPU j3710 @ 1.60 Ghz x 4
Graphics: Intel cherry view
OS type: 64 bit
Disk: 972.9 GB
Monitor: Dell E1916HV

I checked the following folder:
Computer > sys > class > backlight > acpi_video0
The 'backlight' folder has only one folder inside it: acpi_video0

Is it normal to have only one folder in the 'backlight' folder? I think the folder for the graphics card is missing, and it is causing the brightness.

Currently I am adjusting the screen using the following command at the terminal:
xgamma -gamma .75

Please advise me how to solve this problem in the normal way. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a program that comes for ubuntu [Brightness Controller](http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

I am quite sure it will work as it worked for me

Comment: I installed the brightness controller. But after an update, the 'acpi_video0' folder is missing. Now the 'backlight' folder is empty. I cannot find any sliders in the System settings > Brightness and Lock.

Comment: Search for Brightness Controller in your applications menu. When the application opens you will be provided with 2 sliders namely Primary and Secondary and that will serve your purpose